# r - Passing multiple argument to dbGetQuery()? with inner join

Tags: mysql, r

Anyone know where is the problem? I'm using RStudio here

```
sqlStatement <- dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT concat(official_test_cases.id,')', official_test_cases.test_case_name) As id, if (test_cases.description) = "NULL",official_test_cases.name, concat(official_test_cases.name," ", test_cases.description)AS text
FROM official_test_cases
INNER JOIN test_cases ON official_test_cases.test_case = test_cases.id
WHERE !is.null(official_test_cases.name) && !is.null(official_test_cases.id) && !is.null(test_cases.description)")
```

Comment: it keep showing error expected ',' after expression

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with the double quotes. You should try to only have double quotes at the beginning and end of a complete string. If you have double inside the query, R will not parse it in the intended manner.

In short, change the `"NULL"` to `'NULL'` and see if that makes a difference.